# Windows Azure VM Website setup

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure

I have a Windows Azure Virtual Machine. I am able to view my ASP.Net website on the virtual machine (localhost URL). When I ping my Windows Azure Virtual Machine IP I get timeout error.

My domain name is registered with an ISP but I would like to use that domain on my VM website.

Is it possible?

I actually want to know: -

1. How do I access my website outside the VM?
2. I also would like to setup my DNS name.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a couple of questions

> 1. How do I access my web site outside the VM?

If you create a real **Virtual Machine**, based on Windows Server (I guess, since your site is ASP.NET), then you need to redirect traffic on port `80` to that machine. By default when you create `VM` only `RDP` is redirected to your VM, nothing else. You can achieve that in the **ENDPOINTS** tab of your `VM` settings:

In your Windows Azure portal: -

1. Select the VM
2. Click on ENDPOINTS
3. Add ENDPOINT
4. Type some name for the ENDPOINT, put 80 for public and private port

[image]

---

```
2. I also would like to setup my DNS name.
```

I would normally use `CNAME` to point my `www.mydomain.com` to the `myvmname.cloudapp.net`, like with normal Cloud Service development.

However, if you really need to just run your ASP.NET website, I strongly recommend to try using the regular Cloud Service approach (with a WebRole) instead.

**UPDATE**

**`CNAME`**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

I usually add a `CNAME` record for `www.mydomain.com` that points to `mydeployment.cloudapp.net`

You can use it from your domain registrar control panel.

Comment: Whats CNAME and how do I use it ?